# Javascript, Toggle, Slide

Tags: javascript, slidetoggle

http://jsfiddle.net/Z9zD8/271/

```
$(function() 
{
    $('#toggle1').click(function() {
        $('.toggle1').toggle();
        return false;
    });

    $('#toggle2').click(function() {
        $('.toggle2').toggle();
        return false;
    });

    $('#toggle3').click(function() {
        $('.toggle3').toggle();
        return false;
    });

    $('#toggle4').click(function() {
        $('.toggle4').toggle();
        return false;
    });

});
```

I would like, which is always open just a Slider.
Say: I have Slider 1 open. When I open Slider 2, then close Slider 1
.
It should always be open only a Slider

I hope you can help me

thank you

Comment: While the fiddle helps, it is best to paste appropriate code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boxes [.toggle1, .toggle2, .toggle3, ..] should have one one class like '.toggle', and remove [#toggle1, #toggle2, #toggle3, ..] on link elements, and try this jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
   $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.toggle').slideUp();
        $(this).next().next().next('.toggle').slideDown();
   });
});
```

Your html code:

```
<a href="#">Simple Div Toggle</a><br /><br />
<div class="toggle" style="display:none; background-color:#4CF;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>

<a href="#">Simple Div Toggle</a><br /><br />
<div class="toggle" style="display:none; background-color:#4CF;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>

<a href="#">Simple Div Toggle</a><br /><br />
<div class="toggle" style="display:none; background-color:#4CF;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>

<a href="#">Simple Div Toggle</a><br /><br />
<div class="toggle" style="display:none; background-color:#4CF;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just use this jquery code:

**[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9zD8/276/)**

```
$("a[id^='toggle']").click(function(){
      $('div[class^="toggle"]').slideUp(500);
      $("."+$(this).attr("id")).slideToggle(500);        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Jquery UI accordion

[Accordian](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

I think you want this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like so:

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/MbTRD/14/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".flyout").siblings("span").click(function () {
        $(".flyout").slideUp(200, function() {
            $(this).siblings(".flyout").toggle(500);
        });
        $(this).siblings(".flyout").toggle(500);
    });
});


<ul>
<li ><span id="europe">Europe</span>
<div class="flyout">
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>

<li ><span id="europe">Asia</span>
<div class="flyout">
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>

.flyout {display: none}
```